# Attribute errors on loading blender as module in python windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender

I have recently installed blender using conda on python 3.7.
I try to run the following sample script.

```
import bpy


def main(context):
    for ob in context.scene.objects:
        print(ob)


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```

Instead I get the following error:

```
Exception in module register(): 'C:\\Users\\karth\\Anaconda3\\2.79\\scripts\\addons\\io_scene_fbx\\__init__.py'
Exception in module register(): 'C:\\Users\\karth\\Anaconda3\\2.79\\scripts\\addons\\io_anim_bvh\\__init__.py'
Exception in module register(): 'C:\\Users\\karth\\Anaconda3\\2.79\\scripts\\addons\\io_mesh_ply\\__init__.py'
Exception in module register(): 'C:\\Users\\karth\\Anaconda3\\2.79\\scripts\\addons\\io_scene_obj\\__init__.py'
Exception in module register(): 'C:\\Users\\karth\\Anaconda3\\2.79\\scripts\\addons\\io_scene_x3d\\__init__.py'
Exception in module register(): 'C:\\Users\\karth\\Anaconda3\\2.79\\scripts\\addons\\io_mesh_stl\\__init__.py'
Exception in module register(): 'C:\\Users\\karth\\Anaconda3\\2.79\\scripts\\addons\\io_mesh_uv_layout\\__init__.py'
Exception in module register(): 'C:\\Users\\karth\\Anaconda3\\2.79\\scripts\\addons\\io_curve_svg\\__init__.py'
Exception in module register(): 'C:\\Users\\karth\\Anaconda3\\2.79\\scripts\\addons\\cycles\\__init__.py'
<bpy_struct, Object("Cube")>
<bpy_struct, Object("Lamp")>
<bpy_struct, Object("Camera")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karth\Anaconda3\2.79\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py", line 93, in _test_import
    mod = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\karth\Anaconda3\2.79\scripts\startup\bl_ui\__init__.py", line 212, in <module>
    bpy.utils.register_class(UI_UL_list)
AttributeError: expected UIList, UI_UL_list class to have an "bl_idname" attribute
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karth\Anaconda3\2.79\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py", line 176, in register_module_call
    register()
  File "C:\Users\karth\Anaconda3\2.79\scripts\startup\bl_operators\__init__.py", line 68, in register
    register_class(cls)
AttributeError: expected Menu, WM_MT_operator_presets class to have an "bl_idname" attribute
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karth\Anaconda3\2.79\scripts\modules\bpy\utils\__init__.py", line 176, in register_module_call
    register()
  File "C:\Users\karth\Anaconda3\2.79\scripts\startup\keyingsets_builtins.py", line 677, in register
    register_class(cls)
AttributeError: expected KeyingSetInfo, BUILTIN_KSI_LocRot class to have an "bl_idname" attribute
Traceback (most recent call last):

...
    bpy.types.IMAGE_MT_uvs.append(menu_func)
AttributeError: 'RNA_Types' object has no attribute 'IMAGE_MT_uvs'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karth\Anaconda3\2.79\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 350, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "C:\Users\karth\Anaconda3\2.79\scripts\addons\io_curve_svg\__init__.py", line 72, in register
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_import.append(menu_func_import)
AttributeError: 'RNA_Types' object has no attribute 'INFO_MT_file_import'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karth\Anaconda3\2.79\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 350, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "C:\Users\karth\Anaconda3\2.79\scripts\addons\cycles\__init__.py", line 132, in register
    ui.register()
  File "C:\Users\karth\Anaconda3\2.79\scripts\addons\cycles\ui.py", line 1847, in register
    bpy.types.RENDER_PT_render.append(draw_device)
AttributeError: 'RNA_Types' object has no attribute 'RENDER_PT_render'
```

I also couldn't find anything relevant to windows on this. All the errors are AttributeErrors. I have replaced them with "..." since stack won't allow me to add this much code.

Comment: OK seems like it happens only the first time. I ran it second time and it ran well. But one can't seem to use blender in spyder we need to copy and paste the code into blender scripting.